# How to get row in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I get one row by `$id` in Laravel like as:

```
$user = User::where("id", $id)->get();
```

After I need to do `return $user->first();`

Can I use this request more shorty?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply run:

```
return User::find($id);
```

or maybe (depending on your needs) even:

```
return User::findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: where is $id being populated from?

Comment: @Glen This is just example. It can be used from url or any other variable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$user = User::findOrFail($id);` since the `id` is unique so you'll either get a `User` object or Exception which you can catch and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you donot have to call `->get()` and `->first()`, since you are sure that you are going to get only one result by the id column, search like this,

`User::find($id);` 
or
`User::where('id',$id)->first()`

and you have other alternative methods in the case you want to handle exceptions, `->findOrFail()`  or `->firstOrFail()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one where clause, the shortest way will be

```
return User::find($id);
```